# Blend mode layer goes outside image border

Tags: html, css, image, mix-blend-mode

So I use a mix-blend-mode: multiply; effect to create a multiply layer on top of my image when hover on. The problem is the layer goes outside of the image border as in the picture below. I tried to set width and height to the .imgcon  and .imgcon > img (see code below) and the layer fits in but then it messes up the responsive web function when viewed on different screen resolution. So I tried put width and height to 100% to keep the responsive function, but the layer still goes out of the image border.

[image: As you can see, the multiply layer bleeds out of the image]

Heres my code:

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}



.imgcon + div {
 position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
  top: 44%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity:0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  
  letter-spacing: 4px;

}

.imgcon {
 position: relative;
 background: rgba(209, 19, 15, 0);
  transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.imgcon > img {
 transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
}
.imgcon:hover {
  background: #b41f24;
    background: rgba(180, 31, 36, 0.85);


}
.imgcon:hover > img {
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%) ;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;

}

.imgcon:hover + div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="works.html?option=emkoinvite" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>EmKO invitation</h3>
       <span class="category">Identity, print</span>

       <div class="imgwrapper">
       <div class="imgcon">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XmhcxJS.png" /></div>
       <div id="view">view</div></div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.imgwrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.imgcon > img{display:block}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your solution. For an explanation, any block element is by default going to be 100% the width of its parent. If you want the element to remain the widths of its container, you need to use a different `display` attribute; `inline-block` seemed to make the most sense here.

The added space at the bottom is something that many elements have, I call it the descender space. Certain letters like "g" and j" dip below the text line. The parts that dip are called descenders. Many elements leave a little room for descenders. To get rid of this space, you can set `line-height` to 0.

The width and centered text stuff was just an easier way for me to center the text properly.

Let me know if you have any other issues!

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}



.imgcon + div {
 position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 42%;
  width: 256px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity:0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  
  letter-spacing: 4px;

}

.imgcon {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 0;
 background: rgba(209, 19, 15, 0);
  transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.imgcon > img {
 transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
}
.imgcon:hover {
  background: #b41f24;
    background: rgba(180, 31, 36, 0.85);


}
.imgcon:hover > img {
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%) ;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;

}

.imgcon:hover + div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="works.html?option=emkoinvite" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>EmKO invitation</h3>
       <span class="category">Identity, print</span>

       <div class="imgwrapper">
       <div class="imgcon">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XmhcxJS.png" /></div>
       <div id="view">view</div></div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is a `display: inline-block;` on the image's parent:

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.imgcon + div {
 position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
  top: 44%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity:0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.imgcon {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 background: rgba(209, 19, 15, 0);
  transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.imgcon > img {
 transition: ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: ease 0s;
  -o-transition: ease 0s;
}
.imgcon:hover {
  background: #b41f24;
  background: rgba(180, 31, 36, 0.85);
}
.imgcon:hover > img {
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(1.5px) contrast(100%) ;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.imgcon:hover + div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="works.html?option=emkoinvite" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>EmKO invitation</h3>
       <span class="category">Identity, print</span>
       <div class="imgwrapper">
       <div class="imgcon">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XmhcxJS.png" /></div>
       <div id="view">view</div></div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
    </a>
```

That's because that parent is a div, and as such it is a block element and takes all available width. Changing it's `display` to `inline-block` makes it *wrap* to the dimensions of it's children.

Comment: Thank you, but the layer still bleeds out for about 2 pixels at the bottom of the image. Any idea why?